# Is there any way to save preset buys in CS:GO?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

One of the features of CS1.6 and CS:S was the Loadout ability, the ability that allowed the player to quickly purchase a custom load out based on user preference.

However, on the purchase screen for CS:GO, I have been unable to find any "custom" load out screen.  The only options it gives me is: [F1] Buy Auto, [F2] Buy Previous.

And that's it.  I'm terribly confused.  Is this a bug? Or is this intended, on the developer's part?

Comment: You can do this with buyscript macros, but it's a long explanation that I hope someone else writes.

Comment: Here's an example: http://gamebanana.com/css/scripts/5928

Comment: are you planning to dish out the bounty?

Comment: not sure, i'll have to see, if you can elaborate more on adding scripts, that would greatly help (ie weapon names, etc)

Comment: ah sorry, just saw this, ill look into in a bit, thanks though!

Comment: while i was looking for the gun names i discovered something that includes pretty much all of it.  have fun!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Full Tutorial (with possibly all equipment/weapons):
http://www.hattongames.com/2012/06/how-to-create-custom-buy-binds-for-csgo/

Quick Tutorial:
I haven't checked to see if it works, but as Decency said in his post simply make a buy script.  What this does is allow you to bind keys to buying weapons.

Find default.cfg in *Steam\steamapps\common\Counter-Strike Global Offensive\csgo\cfg* and open it in your text editor.

Next add in the script with the things you'd want to buy to the bottom of the existing script. Taking the script pointed out above, you could say:

```
//Print to console
echo "Press F1 for AK-47 / M4A1"

//Set items you want to buy, seperated by semicolon
//alias sets the following word to a variable to be later used
alias "buy_ak-m4" "buy ak47; buy m4a1"

//Then you bind it to a key using the alias!
bind "F1" "buy_ak-m4"
```

What I also noticed is that there is an autobuy.txt script already in csgo, under folder *Steam\steamapps\common\Counter-Strike Global Offensive\csgo*. You can type autobuy into the console, or press F3, and it will work. You could try modifying that script to fit your needs.

autobuy.txt also contains a list of most weapon aliases you can use in the buy-binding script.

Answer (score 3):

As of this moment, there is no way to save load-outs in CS:GO, but it has been in the CS games in the past. So the chance of it coming back in is highly likely.

Unless its intended to be left out to cater to the balance, I predict it will come back some time in the future from a patch.

Comment: Just remember, the patches for this game do add things.. the U.I. has been changed a lot compared to the beginning of the beta. So do not worry about it not coming back.

Answer (score 1):

No - unlike in earlier Counter Strike games, it is not possible to save presets to purchase specific items using an in game interface. This is a [frequently requested feature by the community](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2092690) but hasn't been added to the game in any patches to date, and there is no confirmation from Valve that this may even happen at all.

One alternative to this is to use a keyboard or mouse that supports the creation of custom macros, and then binding a button to a macro which does all of the required keystrokes for your standard loadout (for example b-4-2) to allow you to quickly purchase at the start of a round.

Another alternative is as discussed by [TMP](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/95944/27134), where you create individual bindings that purchase individual groups of items.